# Using unset() to delete node in XML; PHP/simplexml_load_file

Tags: php, arrays, xml, unset

I'm trying to use `unset()` to delete a node in an XML using PHP and can't figure out what is going on here. It doesn't seem to work correctly and I've seen a lot of other questions of similar nature on here but they don't seem to address this issue directly. Here's what my XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <user>
        <name>Test Name 1</name>
        <email>test@test.com</email>
        <spouse/>
    </user>
    <user>
        <name>Test Name 2</name>
        <email>anotherone@test.com</email>
        <spouse>Test Name 3</spouse>
    </user>
</data>
```

My loop that I'm using is like this:

```
url = 'data/users.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

foreach($xml->user as $theUser){
    if($theUser->email[0]=="test@test.com"){
        echo "test";
        unset($theUser);
    }
}
```

When the e-mail matches "test@test.com" I want to be able to delete that whole `user` node. It seems that this should work but I can't figure out why it wouldn't? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SimpleXML` is fine, no need to switch to `DOM`, `unset()` is working fine, if you do it right:

```
unset($theUser[0]);
```

see it working: https://eval.in/228773

**However there will be a problem with your `foreach()`** if you delete a node mid-loop.

I suggest to use `xpath()` instead of a loop, IMO elegant and the code is much simpler.

```
$users = $xml->xpath("/data/user[email='test@test.com']");
```

will create an array of all `<user>` with that email-address.

```
unset($users[0][0]);
```

will delete the first user in that array.

```
foreach ($users as $user) unset($user[0]);
```

will delete the whole array.

see this in action: https://eval.in/228779

Comment: In the example link, it looks like it works great so I like this approach but how would I load this XML from a URL. It keeps giving me an error when I use URL (like simplexml_load_string('data/users.xml'); ) which makes sense because it's reading the URL as a string not a path.

Comment: Oops nevermind, I just have to use file_get_contents() on the URL path. May be good to add to the answer for future people using this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @MillerMedia `simplexml_load_file()` is there to make the object from a file.

Answer (score 2):

SimpeXML is not really meant for changing to the XML structure. Just a simple way of reading the XML.

If you want to manipulate the XML structure you should use the [dom functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.dom.php) and more specifically the [dom_import_simplexml](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.dom-import-simplexml.php). This function allows you to import a SimpleXML element and turn it into a [DomElement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) that can be used for manipulation and that includes deletion.

Here is a code sample that solves your problem and demonstrates the usage of dom_import_simplexml.

```
<?php

$xmlData = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <user>
        <name>Test Name 1</name>
        <email>test@test.com</email>
        <spouse/>
    </user>
    <user>
        <name>Test Name 2</name>
        <email>anotherone@test.com</email>
        <spouse>Test Name 3</spouse>
    </user>
</data>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlData);

foreach($xml->user as $theUser){
    if($theUser->email == 'test@test.com'){
        $dom = dom_import_simplexml($theUser);
        $dom->parentNode->removeChild($dom);
    }
}

echo $xml->asXml();
```

When reading this code you might be thinking why this works since we dont save the new structure anywhere after we have executed the [removeChild](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.removechild.php) function. This works because the DOM functions does not create copies of the underlying objects but instead manipulates them directly.

### Result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>  
    <user>
        <name>Test Name 2</name>
        <email>anotherone@test.com</email>
        <spouse>Test Name 3</spouse>
    </user>
</data>
```